# Protection considerations for powering a microcontroller circuit through USB-C/Micro-USB

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, circuit-protection, usb-c, usb-pd

I am working on a project which utilizes an *Adafruit ESP32 Feather V2 microcontroller* and has a bunch of components requiring 5V.
I will have everything on a perfboard and to power it more easily, I would like to have *either a micro usb or a usb-c connector*.

#### Project details for context

My project consists of 6 RGB LEDs, 3 *74HC595* shift registers, 6 *QRD1114* optical sensors and an amplifier along with a speaker (the exact parts are still to be researched, that is a whole other issue I still have to handle as I don't know how to choose what I need :P). I estimated that with a 5V 3A power supply, I should be able to power both the microcontroller and the components together without lacking current.

I'm aiming to replicate this hobbyist project multiple times once the prototype is done and working like intended. For now I'm using a perfboard but I will at some point design a PCB so that I can just order all components needed at once and solder everything together if I want to reproduce the project so I'm aiming for  a balance of simplicity of wiring and safety for power delivery.

#### USB-C connector possibility considered

I found a [USB-C connector](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/670/ujc_hp2_3_smt_tr-3318783.pdf) designed for power delivery. I'm considering a 5V 3A power supply, but I'm aware that USB-C usually involves power negotiation, which might be beyond my current expertise. The connector I found seems to be receive power only, and I'm wondering if it can simplify the process by not requiring negotiation. If not, I'm open to using micro-USB as an alternative.

---

**I'm wondering how much protection I need to add to the circuit**. I want to do things right and from some research I've found that I can add a PTC Fuse for over current protection, a TVS diode, or some capacitors to stabilize voltage.

Though **I'm not sure how much is too much protection given the scale of my project nor how much is not enough**.

#### My questions

- What are some ways I can make sure I can power my circuit in the safest way possible?
- Are there easier alternatives to power my project?
- More specifically, what protection components are essential for the circuit I have?

---

I will gladly provide more details if needed.

Comment: The largest problem is to draw 3A by any means. No USB specification allows that, unless you negotiate it. Also you are likely not going to find a MicroUSB receptacle rated for 3A. Type-C receptacles rated for 3A do exist. And also I don't understand how you would define a connector being able to only receive power. Drawing 3A literally means you must negotiate it, and I am guessing such currents must be negotiated through USB-PD, or if not, the supply must support signaling with a resistor that there is 3A available. You will damage something if you have a 3A device and plug it to a PC.

Comment: There are some devices such as [Standalone USB PD controller for power sinking devices](https://www.st.com/en/interfaces-and-transceivers/stusb4500.html) which are designed to handle USB-C negotiation of a power delivery contract with a source without MCU support. That device has (a) VBUS under-voltage and over-voltage protection (b) PDO (power data object) customization through NVM. To allow prototyping there are some pre-populated modules such as [USB-C Sink Click](https://www.mikroe.com/usb-c-sink-click).